# Rails NoMethodError in Players#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, erb, nomethoderror

I just used generate scaffold to make this setup and I immediately got this error. For some reason it's trying to evaluate 'user' as a method in line 20 and only user. It went by name fine, but despite them being the exact same code (with different names) it tried to evaluate the second one differently.

```
undefined method `user' for #<Player:0xb66e4798>
```

Extracted source (around line #20):

```
17:   </div>
18:   <div class="field">
19:     <%= f.label :user %><br />
20:     <%= f.text_field :user %>
21:   </div>
22:   <div class="field">
23:     <%= f.label :password %><br />
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/players/new.html.erb

Since this was generated the only thing I myself manually altered was the routes. So here is the part from routes.rb where I changed the root:

```
# root :to => 'welcome#index'
root :to => "players#index"
```

Comment: nevermind, thanks nbarraille. the user was called username in the table, but user in the model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably declared your form `f` like this: `<%= form_for @player do |f| %>`. Then, when you use `f.text_field`, rails magic tries to match your symbol to one of `@player` property.

If `:user` is not an instance variable of `Player`, then, you need `FormTagHelper#text_field_tag` instead:

```
17:   </div>
18:   <div class="field">
19:     <%= f.label :user %><br />
20:     <%= text_field_tag :user %>
21:   </div>
22:   <div class="field">
23:     <%= f.label :password %><br />
```